# JUnit = red bar, even if my assertEquals is correct

Tags: java, junit

```
package dpackage;

public class MyCalculator {

    public int getSum(int a, int b, int sum) {
        sum = a+b;
        return sum;
    }

}

package dpackage;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class MyCalculatorTest extends TestCase {
    MyCalculator calc = new MyCalculator();

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
    }

    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
    }
    protected void getSum(){
        int a=2;
        int b=3;
        int sum = a+b;
        assertEquals(5, calc.getSum(a, b, sum));
    }

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't your test be called `testGetSum()` in JUnit 3? Notice the `test` prefix.

Comment: You should try reading the reasons for failure before trying to fix what you think is the problem. I believe the reason for failure in this case will be "no tests found in MyCalculatorTest".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is a bit subtle. Change the code to below to get the green bar.

```
  public void testGetSum()
```

In Junit 3 the test methods should start with `test` and be `public`

If possible, I would recommend you moving on to Junit 4, which does not impose such restrictions.

Using annotations such as `@Test` , `@Before` and `@After` your code will be much simpler and easier to read.

Also passing in `sum` to the method and then recalculating it looks redundant. Stick with calculating it within your `getSum` method .

Answer (score 3):

You don't have any method which name begins with "test". You might rename your "getSum" method to "testGetSum" in MyCalculatorTest class.

Comment: Actually Ajay's answer below is much more accurate than mine

Answer (score 2):

What's the point of this definition?

```
public int getSum(int a, int b, int sum) {
    sum = a+b;
    return sum;
}
```

Just use:

```
public int getSum(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

and

```
public void testGetSum() { <-- note test in front
    int a=2;
    int b=3;
    assertEquals(5, calc.getSum(a, b));
}
```

Note that the error reported by eclipse without `test` in front of the method is that there is no test class detected.

Comment: I think that test methods should be declared public; or is it ok to be protected in junit 3